# Send parameter to WebApi Action with Postman?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

I have the following Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetByUsername(string username)
{
    return Ok(_userBusinessComponent.GetUserByUsername(username));
}
```

How can I send `username` to this action via `Postman`
I tried the followings, nothing response:

[image: Postman Screenshot]

[image: Postman Screenshot]

I change the signature of action as the following:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetByUsername([FromBody]string username)
```

This time username is always null !!!

Comment: did you try `http://localhost:51671/api/User/GetByUsername?username="Mohammad"` ?

Comment: @ibubi that works! Thanks. but how can I send this parameter with JSON to action.

Comment: AFAIK because you are sending an object from Postman, your parameter type should be a complex type, say it `User` object, instead `string username`, use `User user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `ibubi` said, for the following web api action

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetByUsername(string username)
{
    return Ok(_userBusinessComponent.GetUserByUsername(username));
}
```

I have to use the following code:

```
http://localhost:51671/api/User/GetByUsername?username=Moha‌​mmad
```